# Retry method considering its result

Tags: java, spring-retry, retry-logic

I have some method, that returns object with field `boolean done`:

```
public OperationResponse getOperationResponse(YaRequest request) {
    // ...
}
```

```
class OperationResponse {
    boolean done;
}
```

And if `done == false` I have to retry this method. At most I can retry it 4 times. Using `@Retryable` will not help here, since `@Retryable` is focused on exceptions and cannot be reoriented to result values. Throwing an exception doesn't seem like a good option either. Perhaps someone can suggest a more optimal solution?

Comment: "Throwing an exception doesn't seem like a good option either." Why not? You would be able to use `@Retryable` to get the retry behavior you want, and  you'd get an `ExhaustedRetryException` if the operation never succeeds, which you can then handle in your calling code.

Comment: As a result, I actually used throwing an exception. I just thought that maybe there is some tool/library that can make the implementation more elegant.